# SharePoint Designer Datasource only showing 30 items

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I'm running into a weird issue with SharePoint Designer 2010. When editing my DVWP in design mode, I normally can click within the web part and then cycle through my datasource rows using the "Data Source Details" pane. In this case, though, I am only able to cycle through the first 30 items of the list. That in itself might not be bad, but apparently the DVWP itself only has access to the first 30 items as well. The default view of the list is set to show items in batches of 300. I've checked another DVWP that's almost identical and confirmed that I can cycle through all 172 items in that list.

Has anyone seen this kind of thing before?

UPDATE: Just to clarify, this isn't in the paging of the DVWP itself - the web part shows a single record at a time based on a filter that matches the current site URL to a column in the list. The 30-item limit is on the datasource rows in the Data Source Details pane. It's still causing an actual issue with the web part, however, since the DVWP only seems to have access to the first 30 items in the list. If the current site URL is a match for item #31 in the list, the DVWP will tell me it can't find a match, whereas items #1 thru #30 work correctly.

Comment: Many times it's just easier to delete and rebuild the web part. But if you want to try and fix it, I'd start ensuring that the web part you're looking at is indeed using the default view settings. If so, I'd try a Ctrl + F in the code behind for 30 (and, failing that, for 31); they might be stopping more rows from being displayed in the XSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a solution for the issue, but instead created a new DVWP for the same datasource - which did not have the 30-item limit issue - and then copied my dvt1.rowview template over into the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Paging Options to Display All Items, the default when a DVWP is created is 30 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are able to see only 30 items in DVWP.
If that is the case you need to update paging for your DVWP. Select Show all items in the Paging property.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, I didn't mean for that to occur, I am trying to resolve it.

Comment: I upvoted to compensate for the down vote